# Round-off error step choice

Tags: matlab, error-estimation

In the [Numerical Recipes](https://www.cec.uchile.cl/cinetica/pcordero/MC_libros/NumericalRecipesinC.pdf) in *section 5.7.- Numerical derivatives* the choice of the step size $h$ in the numerical derivative should lead to a difference between $x$ and $x+h$ representable by an exact number. In  C, the program steps are:

```
temp = x + h
h = temp - x
```

**Question**: What is the meaning of these steps?

**Question**: How can choose $h$ as an "exact" number in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna answer by points:

1. NR authors are referring to the fact that $h$ itself is affected by roundoff too. Also, if your $h$ does not have a **finite** binary representation, like $h = 0.1$, you're sure you have error for every $h$ in your code.

What you really want is that the difference between $x$ and $x+h$ is **exactly** representable in finite precision arithmetic.

2. Just do what they wrote: don't choose $h$ s.t. the increment in not exactly representable in finite precision. A good way could be to set $h= 2^{-k}$, for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (of course not too big...), so you know its representation is exact ;)